# Display output after selection from two dropdown menus

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I am new to python streamlit package and I have data that I have created 2 dropdown menus. One dropdown menu selects hospital name and another select document source. Here is how my data looks like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Hospital': ['Nick hospital', 'Nick hospital', 'Nick hospital',
                                'Krish hospital', 'Krish hospital', 'Krish hospital'],
                   'document_source': ['NAR', 'PAR', 'Free Text', 'NAR', 'PAR', 'Free Text'],
                   'document_count': [1200, 150, 3, 2500, 342, 300]})
df.head()
```

Now I want to display document count after hospital and document source has been selected.Here is my streamlit code creating dropdowns

```
import streamlit as st
#create sidebar
st.sidebar.title("Filter data")

temp = df.to_dict('list')
temp['Hospital'] = list(set(temp['Hospital']))
temp['document_source'] = list(set(temp['document_source']))
temp_records = df.to_dict('records')

#Checkbox for Hospitals
hosp_list = st.sidebar.selectbox("Select Hospital", temp['Hospital'])


#Chech box for Documents
doc_source = st.sidebar.selectbox("Select Document source", temp['document_source'])

st.subheader('Document Count')
```

Expected output is to show document count per hospital selected. so If I select a hospital and select document source I should get the document count of that document in bold blue colour. could someone out there help please

Comment: What output are you getting? How is it different from what you're expecting?

Comment: @EricMPastore I can select hospital and Document source well from dropdowns but I am stuck on how I can call those selections to output document count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to be using DataFrame conditions to do [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) into your data.

Here's a working version that outputs what you're looking for, based on your dataset:

```
st.subheader('Document Count')

# Create two conditions
hospital_condition = df['Hospital'] == hosp_list
doc_source_condition = df['document_source'] == doc_source

# Select all rows that meet those conditions.
# There should be exactly one!
rows = df[hospital_condition & doc_source_condition]

if len(rows) == 1:
    st.write(rows["document_count"][0])
else:
    # Sanity check. This shouldn't be possible!
    st.error("Matched an unexpected number of rows!")
    st.write(rows)
```